# " ORDER BY order" at the end of MySQL query is causing problems

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php script that pulls content from a database and prints them in a certain fashion. The database has a column-header called "order" which is an INT size 11. I'm trying to order the contents by the value "order" in the database when I'm getting data from it, like this:

```
<?php

$db_hostname = '<hostname>';
$db_database = '<db>';
$db_username = '<username>';
$db_password = '<password>';
$db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
mysql_select_db($db_database, $db_server);

$query = "SELECT * FROM <table> ORDER BY order"; // why is "ORDER BY order" problematic...
$table = mysql_query($query);

$data_items = '';
$carousel_items = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($table)) {
// ...etc
```

There are few rows in the database I'm getting information from, and the query `"SELECT * FROM <table>"` works exactly the way it should. What am I doing wrong?

If it helps, the error I'm getting back (on the website that this script is for):
`Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /$PATH/php/myfile.php on line 15`

Line 15 is `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($table)) {`

I'm aware that if I wasn't lazy I could sort this out without the MySQL query and, because php is absurdly flexible, do something like `$array[$row['order']] = $row['what I want'];`, but I'd like a solution that doesn't have to add those (what should be) unnecessary lines. I've also tried adding the semicolon (just to be sure) to the end of my query, but it doesn't change anything at all.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: `mysql_query` is super old and being removed from PHP in the future. If this is new code, you'd be better off writing it with PDO from the start than to have to fix it later on.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll do that.

Answer (score 5):

`order` is a reserved word, surround it with backticks

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM <table> ORDER BY `order`";
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Don't know why I didn't think of that before. Thank you so much! :-)

Comment: @UtkashDubey Could also use the time to give it more descriptive non-reserved name :)

Answer (score 0):

Since `order` is a keyword you need to enclose it in backticks if you want to use it as an identifier:

```
SELECT * FROM <table> ORDER BY `order`
```

Answer (score 0):

Order is a reserved word in mysql. Use backticks to surround the reserved word like this:

```
"ORDER BY `order`"
```

Documentation here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html